# MYSQL Trigger to calculate percent

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I'm trying to calculate the percentage column in my table `project` after an update occurs on any of the following columns `fund` and `goal`.

This is the query I made up:

```
  CREATE TRIGGER percentcalc AFTER UPDATE ON project 
  FOR EACH ROW 
    SET percent = ( fund / goal ) *100
```

but I seem to get an error:

> #1193 - Unknown system variable 'percent'

Answer (score 1):

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER percentcalc AFTER UPDATE ON project 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET NEW.percent = ( NEW.fund / NEW.goal ) * 100;
END
//
delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two major problems:

1. You have to use `NEW` keyword to access values of columns of a row that is being updated
2. You can't change values of `NEW` variables in an `AFTER` trigger. If you try to do so you'll get *'Updating of NEW row is not allowed in after trigger'* error. Therefore you have to use  only **`BEFORE`** event for your trigger

> **[Trigger Syntax and Examples](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html)**
>   ...Within the trigger body, **the OLD and NEW keywords enable you to
>   access columns in the rows**  affected by a trigger. (OLD and NEW are not
>   case sensitive.)...
>
> ...In a **BEFORE trigger, you can also change its value
>   with SET NEW.col_name = value** if you have the UPDATE privilege for it.
>   This means you can use a trigger to modify the values to be inserted
>   into a new row or used to update a row. (**Such a SET statement has no
>   effect in an AFTER trigger** because the row change will have already
>   occurred.)...

That being said your trigger should look like

```
CREATE TRIGGER percentcalc 
BEFORE UPDATE ON project 
FOR EACH ROW 
   SET NEW.percent = (NEW.fund / NEW.goal) * 100;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5cff7/1)** demo